# Monte Carlo integration in R

Tags: r

I need to apply [Monte Carlo](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonteCarloIntegration.html) integration to a function using R. I am able to plot the equation, but am unaware on how to plot random points over it.

Would appreciate any insight on how to do that.

The function I'm using to plot, is the basic plot() function with `x` as the desired range and `y` as the equation.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to just plot points or are you asking how to do monte carlo integration?

Comment: I'm okay with the Monte Carlo process. I just want to know how to plot random point and an equation together.

Comment: Do you want to plot random point over the function or all over the plot? I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish..

Comment: @ Dr. Mike, all over. Something like this http://www.infosysblogs.com/infosys-labs/images/MCIntegration1.png

Comment: It looks like @isal only wants to know how to add points to a plot. I tried to answer this. Could someone with more rep please retag the question? It really has little to do with Monte Carlo.

Comment: @isal - That graphic is horrible.  The "points" are unrelated to the function being plotted and do nothing but distract from the actual plot itself.  I'm guessing you want to do so something that isn't exactly equivalent...

Comment: Yes, I should have given it a better look. I apologize. I need random points on the graph and then calculate the number of them that fall underneath the curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nicest way to plot a curve is to use the `curve` function:

```
f = function(x) x^2 + 1   
curve(f(x), -2,2, ylim=c(0, 5))
```

You can then add points to the plot via the `points` function:

```
points(runif(100, -2, 2), runif(100, 0, 6))
```

and calculate the Monte-Carlo estimate using a comparison:

```
N = 100000
sum(f(runif(N, -2, 2)) > runif(N, 0, 6))/N * (4*6)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That was nice and detailed.

Comment: If I could ask you one more question. How do I compare points to the function? Say, if x,y = (1.455,1.224), how do I check if it falls under f?

Comment: @isal That's what the last line of code does. For particular points, use: `f(x) > y`

Answer (score 1):

You can generate random points with

```
xx <- runif(100,min=0,max=1)
yy <- runif(100,min=0,max=1)
```

and add them to an existing plot with

```
points(xx,yy)
```

See `?points` for the help page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of a solution given that I understand you correctly.

Basic code:

```
    x<-seq(-4,4,0.1)
    y<-2*x^2-3*x
    plot(x,y)
    points(x, rnorm(length(x), 20, 10), col="red")
```

This adds random points coloured in red to your existing function.

[image: Visual]